# How to peek StreamSocket for data in UWP apps

Tags: c#, sockets, uwp

With Socket class, I can use Socket.ReceiveAsync method passing SocketFlags.Peek flag. I don't see anything similar for StreamSocket, however.

UWP's InputStreamOptions enum provides Partial and ReadAhead flags but from their description it does not seem they are for the same purpose (checking data availability leaving the data in the input buffer).

Comment: You have to look at the base stream for the properties,  You can use the seek() method to move around the buffer.

Comment: Is it safe to call Seek on StreamSocket's InputStream? Unlike file streams, network streams usually don't support seeking..

Comment: Not sure.  The only real issue is to make sure you don't move past the current position (last byte added).  I wish that Microsoft created a unix like stream that has both an input position and an output position.  Having only a current position is confusing.

Comment: @jdweng The real issue is NotSupportedException being thrown on any attempt to call Seek on a network-kind stream (including StreamSocket-related streams).